# custom size paper in MPFD

Tags: php, mpdf

i tried for set custom size paper in MPDF like this

```
$mpdf = new mPDF('utf-8', array(190,236));
```

but cannot work, anyone know how it's work?

Answer (score 1):

I just tested your class initialization in the included example `example01_basic.php` and it's working fine. Maybe you just don't recognize the difference with your eyes. Try something more visible like `$mpdf = new mPDF('utf-8', array(130, 130));`.

Give it a try with this example file:

```
$html = '<h1>my test headline</h1><p>that is my body text</p>';
require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
$mpdf = new mPDF('utf-8', array(130, 130));

$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output();
exit;
```

**Edit:**

As you pointed out in your comment, you want to change the margin of the page. You could edit the page styles via CSS.

**For testing** add the following CSS Snippet to your PDF included HTML:

```
<style>
@page {
    margin-top: 10mm;
    margin-bottom: 10mm;
    margin-left: 5mm;
    margin-right: 5mm;
}
</style>
```

If you want to style your page **for production use**, you should take a look in the MPDF included `example13_paging_css.php`. Here you can see the recommended way to use stylesheets in MPDF.

```
// LOAD a stylesheet
$stylesheet = file_get_contents('mpdfstylePaged.css');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);    // The parameter 1 tells that this is css/style only and no body/html/text
```

Comment: what file autoload.php?

Comment: It's the autoloader located in your MPDF `\vendor` directory. That's how you include the library in your project. See also the [Creating your first file](https://mpdf.github.io/getting-started/creating-your-first-file.html) section in the manual.

Comment: include_once APPPATH.'/third_party/mpdf/mpdf.php';
 i user this, it's different?

Comment: That should also work fine. Do you get PDF output at all or some error message?